# NextJS: Render Markdown with table

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my Nextjs project, I'm receiving some markdown through and API, and I need to display it in the Nextjs page.

My code looks as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next"
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown"
import gfm from 'remark-gfm'
import Layout from "../../components/Layout"
import { PostProps } from "../../components/Post"
import { server } from '../../config';

const fetchSinglePostServer = async (id) => {
  const res = await fetch(server + '/api/post/' + id);
  return res.json();
}


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {

  const post = await fetchSinglePostServer(params.id);
    return {
      props: post,
    };
};

const Post: React.FC<PostProps> = (props) => {
  let title = props.title

return (
    <Layout title={title}>
      <main className="container mx-auto mt-6 px-2 dark:bg-gray-800">
        <div className="flex md:space-x-4 justify-center">
          <div className="mb-4">
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold my-2">{title}</h2>
              <p className="mb-2">By {props?.author?.name || "Unknown author"}</p>
              <div className="prose lg:prose-lg">
                <ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[gfm]}>{props.markdown}</ReactMarkdown>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Post
```

This whole code works great WITHOUT `remarkPlugins={[gfm]}`.

However, my markdown contains a table and to display that table I need to use this plugin.

Using this plugin breaks the page. I receive `Server Error TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`

I'm looking for solution to display this api-received markdown content in my nextjs page when the markdown contains table also.

My Sample markdow:

```
This is an example post, with a [link](https://nextjs.org) and a React component:
  
  The title and description are pulled from the MDX file and processed using gray-matter. Additionally, links are rendered using a custom component passed to next-mdx-remote.
  
  Go back [home](/).
  
  # Table

  | Branch  | Commit           |
  | ------- | ---------------- |
  | main    | 0123456789abcdef |
  | staging | fedcba9876543210 |
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the markdown with the table you're trying to render? I can't seem to replicate the issue.

Comment: I've added my sample markdown above. Note that it works just fine. The issue happens only when I add the plugin remarkPlugins={[gfm]} for the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not at all difficult to write your own table interpreter. below I give an example through html insertion ( like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`), but if you slightly redesign the functions, you can make a completely component insertion - it's possible.

```js
const text = `  
  | Branch  | Commit           |
  | ------- | ---------------- |
  | main    | 0123456789abcdef |
  | staging | fedcba9876543210 | 


  | Branch  | Commit           |Comment |
  | ------- | ---------------- | ------ |
  | main    |                  | old    |
  | staging | fedcba9876543210 | new    | 
`

const findTables = (text) => {
  const tables = [];
  let table = null
  let  isTable = false;
  const lines = text.split('\n')
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    const line = lines[i].trim();
    let row = '';
    if (row = line.match(/^\|(.*)\|$/)) {
      if(!isTable){
        isTable = true
        table = []; // new table
      }
      table.push(row[1].split('|'));
    } else {
      if (isTable) {
        tables.push(table)
      }
      isTable = false;
    }
  }
  return tables
}

// is it | ------- | ---------------- |  ?
const isHeaderBreak = (row) => row
  .reduce((acc, e) => acc &&  !!e.trim()
    .match(/^\-+$/), true)

// <tr><td></td>...</tr>
const makeRow = (rawRow) => {
  const data =  rawRow.reduce((acc, e )=> `${acc}<td>${e.trim()}</td>`, '')
  let row = `<tr>${data}</tr>\n`
  return row;
}

const makeTable = (table) => {
  let header = '';
  let body = '';
  let isHeader = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
    if (isHeaderBreak(table[i])) {
      isHeader = false;
      continue;
    }
    if (isHeader) header += makeRow(table[i]);
    else body += makeRow(table[i]); 
  }
  return `<table border="1">
  <thead>
  ${header}<thead>
  <tbody>
  ${body}</tbody>
  </table>
  `
}

const tables = findTables(text);
for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++){
  document.write(makeTable(tables[i]))
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not at all, I'm glad you took it okay. Some programmers don't like reinventing the wheel. And I do not like to use any that you can implement yourself in a smaller volume for the desired task). Of course there are many useful libraries out there and all is well as long as they work.

Comment: I just got to know about the library next-mdx-remote and this solved my problem.

Comment: Grate! when problems are solved, anyway :)